# Almost sure convergence of the sum of a series of non-identical random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have a sequence of r.v.s $Y_n$ for $n\geq 0$. Suppose $\mathbb{P}(Y_n=1)=\mathbb{P}(Y_n=-1)=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y_n=0)=1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}$. We have $X_n=\sum_{t=1}^n (\frac{1}{4})^{n-t} Y_{t-1}$ for $n\geq1.$ $Y_1,Y_2,\cdots$ are indepdent.

I wonder if $X_n\rightarrow 0$ almost surely? Maybe it is not. I don't know how to show it. Can Borel-cantelli help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} P\{Y_n \neq 0\}<\infty$. Hence $Y_n=0$ eventually with probability $1$. Since $|(\frac 1 4) ^{n-t}| \leq 1$ we see that $X_n$ is Cauchy, hence converges almost surely. Now combine with the answer by Stefan Lafon to conclude that the limit is almost surely $0$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $E(X_n)=0$, and assuming the random variables are independent, 
$$\begin{split}
E(X_n^2)&=\sum_{t=1}^n \left(\frac 1{16}\right)^{n-t}E(Y_{t-1}^2)\\
&=\sum_{t=1}^n \left(\frac 1{16}\right)^{n-t}\frac 1{2^{t-1}}\\
&=\left(\frac 1 {16}\right)^{n-1}\sum_{t=1}^n \left(\frac 1{16}\right)^{1-t}\frac 1{2^{t-1}}\\
&=\left(\frac 1 {16}\right)^{n-1}\frac{8^n-1}7
\end{split}$$
So $E(X_n^2)\rightarrow 0$.
Using [Markov's inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality), you can see that for any $a>0$, $$P(X_n^2>a) \rightarrow 0$$
From which your can conclude the convergence to $0$ almost surely.

Comment: Doesn’t Markov here yield a convergence in probability rather?

Comment: Thanks. Isn't $\mathbb{P}(X_n^2 > a)\rightarrow 0$ convergence in probability?

Answer (score 0):

With Borel-Cantelli, you prove that there exists an integer-valued random variable $N$ such that almost surely, $\forall n \geq N,\,Y_n=0$.

Then, almost surely, for all $n \geq N$, $X_n \leq 4^{-n}\sum_{t=0}^N{4^{t+1}|Y_t|} \leq 4^{-n+N+2}$.

Thus $X_n \rightarrow 0$ almost surely.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea. But how can you conclude $\forall n \geq N, Y_n=0$ almost surely? Note that $\mathbb{P}(Y_{N+1}=0)=1-\frac
{1}{2^{N+1}}\neq 0$.

Comment: Yes, but $\sum{P(Y_n \neq 0)} < \infty$ and you use Borel-Cantelli.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks.